# How to run python script with arguments using ShellExecuteW?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to run python script with arguments using WinAPI function ShellExecuteW.

It looks like a

```
python .\PythonDLL_Example.py 125960 126110 126070 126250 3928 274353.845945816 119761.8349277858 18080.59072693367 -252416.3714632094 -79682.09253258759 -12446.11663140202
```

I tried to do like this using full paths, just in case:

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, "C:\\Users\\Amber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe", "C:\\Users\\Amber\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\DEA332DEFF5165CB2EAFB6F9BD062C50\\MQL5\\Experts\\Advisors\\PythonDLL_Example.py 125960 126110 126070 126250 3928 274353.845945816 119761.8349277858 18080.59072693367 -252416.3714632094 -79682.09253258759 -12446.11663140202", NULL, 10);
```

No result
Error %d42

Test execution like below run successfully:

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, "open", "C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, 10);
```

Please, ho to execute my script?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `ShellExecute()` for this.  Since you are trying to invoke `python.exe` directly, you should be using `CreateProcess()` instead

Comment: Remy is correct. Use CreateProcess for this. Even then, you'll need to supply the working directory, just as you need to whe calling ShellExecute, although your code does not.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved my case:

1. I associated .py files with python.exe in my OS Windows. So, I do not use "python .\PythonDLL_Example.py ....." I use ".\PythonDLL_Example.py ....." instead.
2. I sorted out, that "%d42" is not an error. This is HINSTANCE of process. I found a mistake of my script (no transmitted arguments to script).
3. for me, correct is:

   ```
   ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, "C:\\Users\\Amber\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\DEA332DEFF5165CB2EAFB6F9BD062C50\\MQL5\\Experts\\Advisors\\PythonDLL_Example.py", "125960 126110 126070 126250 3928 274353.845945816 119761.8349277858 18080.59072693367 -252416.3714632094 -79682.09253258759 -12446.11663140202", NULL, SW_HIDE);
   ```